# Template argument deduction/substitution failed in a simple inheritance case

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is my minimal example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    using Storage = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type; 

    template<typename T>
    Base(Storage<T>*)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    using Storage = Storage<T>;

    Derived(Storage* storage) :
            Base{storage}
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int>::Storage storage;  
    Derived<int> derived {&storage};
}
```

When compiling that with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` I get this error:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived<T>::Derived(Derived<T>::Storage*) [with T = int; Derived<T>::Storage = std::aligned_storage<4ul, 4ul>::type]’:
test.cpp:30:32:   required from here
test.cpp:23:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    Base{storage}
                ^
test.cpp:23:16: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:11:2: note: template<class T> Base::Base(Base::Storage<T>*)
  Base(Storage<T>*)
  ^
test.cpp:11:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:23:16: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
    Base{storage}
                ^
```

Any idea how to solve that? It seems pretty simple, yet the compiler cannot deal with it... I tried some weird casting in the construction of object, or modifications to the definition of `Derived`'s constructor, but the errors suggested that I was going in the wrong direction...

Comment: You have a non-deduced context in your `Base` constructor parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - any suggestion for a solution? The info I found about that on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts is not very helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `using` alias introduces a non-deduced context into the `Base` class constructor. This causes a substitution failure because `T` cannot be deduced. A solution would be to deduce `T` through another parameter by tag-dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
struct no_decay { };

class Base
{
    // ...
public:
    template<typename T>
    Base(Storage<T>*, no_decay<T>);
};

// ...

Derived(Storage* storage)
    : Base(storage, no_decay<T>{})
{ }
```

Now `T` will be deduced by the second argument, not the first.

Comment: OK, great - this indeed helps. I assume that the root cause of the problem is that `T` is present in the "outer" template, but I'm passing in `...::type` inner type into the constructor, which additionally only uses size and alignment of `T` only, right? Or maybe that's only because `T` is used in `sizeof()` and `alignof()` and nothing else matters? Is there any way I could use this trick without introducing a new `no_decay` type? Maybe there's something in the STL that I could use?

Comment: @FreddieChopin The problem is that you have a nested name specifier acting as a dependent typename, which by definition is non-deducible. The reasons for using the `no_decay` template is 1) to prevent unnecessary construction of a `T` object just to deduce its type and 2) because constructors cannot take explicit template arguments, all types need to be deduced. Therefore `no_decay` is necessary. An alternative would be to have `Base` be a template taking `T`, and removing the `template<…>` from the `using` alias and constructor.

Comment: @FreddieChopin [Here's your example with `Base` taking `T`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eb1c85890ef892e2) Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately I need Base to be non-templated, so your original solution is better than this one.